# Docker - how to set iface name when creating a new network

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose, nic

After creating a new network with:

`docker network create test-net`

and running `ifconfig` on the host, a new interface name is being listed:

```
br-f2b630e4e141 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:48:fe:cb:86  
          inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

1. Is there a way to create this network and specify the iface name, for example *docker1* or *test-net*?
2. In case of `docker-compose`, can we also specify iface name inside the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: Have you checked [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981224/docker-how-to-specify-iface-name-when-creating-a-new-network)

Comment: @Rao, I checked again and it seems I've found something :-)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### 1. with docker network command

There is a `--opt` option which can be used like this:

`docker network create --opt com.docker.network.bridge.name=br_test test-net`

and it seems to work:

```
$ ifconfig
br_test   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:8f:3b:24:32  
          inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

found about `--opt` here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#the-dockergwbridge-network

#### 2. with docker-compose

inside the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
networks:
  test-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     driver: default
     config:
       - subnet: 172.100.0.0/16
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: br_test
```

Comment: Please specify the version of docker-compose where this option: `com.docker.network.bridge.name` is applicable.

Comment: @belabrinel found that it still applicable https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/

Comment: Notice: error `failed to check bridge interface existence: numerical result out of range` means the specified interface name is too long.

Comment: version 3.7 works